# Sonarlint not highlighting issues in Visual Studio Enterprise 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019, sonarlint

I've installed the `Sonarlint` extension in the `Visual Studio Enterprise 2019` and restarted it and then it is not highlighting any issues in the project. Sonarlint with the standalone mode.

Here is the settings and has nothing,

```
{
  "sonarlint.rules": {},
}
```

Any ideas?